# Integer data type conversion from string

Tags: python, pandas

I was working on one data frame series's column whose Data type was 'object' (str).
its format was like '301,694'.

I want data type of that column from panda series to be int or float.
Received errors when I tried below code.

please share knowledge.

1)

```
df2['Total Ballots Counted'] = df2['Total Ballots Counted'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

error received - invalid literal for int() with base 10: '301,694'

2)

```
df2['Total Ballots Counted'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['Total Ballots Counted'])
```

error received - Unable to parse string "301,694" at position 1

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: ```int(str(number).replace(',',''))``` to get 301694 from 301,694

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',',''))` before converting with `.astype(int)`?

Comment: Python does not use the comma to separate the real part of a number, but use the dot. Perhaps this is the problem. For example: `a=3.14` and `b=3,14` will results data types: `a` as `float` and `b` as `tuple`.

Comment: @LazyCoder suggestion helped me. I split the string and remove the comma by hard code. and later converted into an int.  Somehow replace is not working as " , " is part of string , not standalone string. eg. " 301,694 ".

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
df['Total Ballots Counter'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:
`df['colname'] = df['colname'].replace(',', '').astype(int)`

Another thing to do is :

`int(''.join([i for i in str(number).split('') if i is not ',']))` for each number in the column.

Comment: I tried this, it did not work as it was looking for a comma as whole str, but in our case " , " is part of string.     eg. "123,123"

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
pd.to_numeric(df2['Total Ballots Counted'].replace({',':'.'},regex=True), errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

@LazyCoder suggestion helped me. I split the string and remove the comma by hard code. and later converted into an int.  Somehow "replace" function is not working as " , " is part of a string , not a standalone string. eg. " 301,694 ".

```
def remove_coma(item):   
   str2=''
   for i in item:
           if i is not ',':                             
               str2 += str2.join(i)
   return int(str2)          

df['Total Ballots Counted'] = df['Total Ballots Counted'].apply(lambda item:remove_coma(item))
```

Please share if there is any better and short way.